# Dockerfile's ADD and COPY commands don't work

Tags: docker, heroku, dockerfile

After I build my image and shell into the container, I won't see any of the files/dirs that I supposedly added/copied.
I'm uploading the container into Heroku, and running bash to look around. 
Once I shell in, at the root level, I am in a dir called `app`.

I've tried multiple permutations of the commands in the same Dockerfile. Nothing works..

```
COPY . app/
COPY . /app/
COPY config config/
ADD luup luup/
COPY luup ./luup/
COPY luup app/luup/
COPY ./luup app/luup/
COPY luup app/
COPY requirements requirements/
COPY manage.py manage.py
ADD ./config /config/
ADD ./config /app/config/
ADD ./config /app/config
```

What gives?

Here is a trimmed down tree:

```
.
├── Dockerfile.django
├── Dockerfile.local
├── Dockerfile.test
├── LICENSE
├── Procfile
├── README.rst
├── compose
│   ├── local
│   │   └── django
│   │       ├── celery
│   │       │   ├── beat
│   │       │   │   └── start.sh
│   │       │   └── worker
│   │       │       └── start.sh
│   │       └── start.sh
│   └── production
│       ├── caddy
│       │   ├── Caddyfile
│       │   └── Dockerfile.caddy
│       ├── django
│       │   ├── Dockerfile.django
│       │   ├── celery
│       │   │   ├── beat
│       │   │   │   └── start.sh
│       │   │   └── worker
│       │   │       └── start.sh
│       │   ├── entrypoint.sh
│       │   └── gunicorn.sh
│       └── postgres
│           ├── Dockerfile.postgres
│           └── maintenance
├── config
│   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── wsgi.cpython-36.pyc
│   ├── settings
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __pycache__
│   │   │   ├── __init__.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   │   └── production.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   ├── base.py
│   │   ├── local.py
│   │   ├── production.py
│   │   └── test.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── docs
│   ├── Makefile
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── make.bat
├── heroku.yml
├── local.yml
├── locale
│   └── README.rst
├── luup
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── contrib
│   ├── static
│   │   ├── base.html
│   │   ├── pages
│   │   │   ├── about.html
│   │   │   └── home.html
│   │   └── users
├── manage.py
├── requirements
│   ├── base.txt
│   ├── local.txt
│   └── production.txt
```

There are multiple Dockerfiles, but the ones I'm using/testing with, are at root.

Here's what it looks like when I shell in:

```
Running bash on ⬢ boiling-anchorage-81724... up, run.2463 (Free)
~ $ pwd
/app
~ $ ls
~ $ ls
~ $ cd ..
/ $ ls
app  bin  dev  etc  lib  lib64  lost+found  proc  sbin  sys  tmp  usr  var
```

As you can see, there's nothing there. `ls` returns nothing. This is the result of the Dockerfile that I've used above--with the many `COPY` and `ADD` statements.

Can someone please help? I've been banging my head on this for the past few days..

Really messing everything up, this one *does* work:

```
COPY ./requirements /usr/src/app/requirements
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r /usr/src/app/requirements/production.txt
```

Because it does end up installing all of the requirements.
I've also tried copying files/dirs into /usr/src/app, but even if I do, I won't see it when I shell in.

EDIT: According to [heroku here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime#dockerfile-commands-and-runtime),
"The working directory is /. You can set a different directory using WORKDIR."

EDIT: Besides the Dockerfile, are there any other configurations that I should be looking at?

Comment: Can you show the cli output of your build running and the `docker run` command so we can verify it's the same image being run that you built? Is there anything in a `.dockerignore` file?

Comment: @BMitch yes, I did it now. Uploaded the build output for Dockerfile.test as well as the contents of Dockerfile.test.  The current ADD/COPY commands there "work"(as in they'll deploy without error) but the files/dirs they supposedly copied do not actually show up when I shell into the container. If you see no problem with the code here, I'll assume the problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have `WORK_DIR /app` specified in the Dockerfile,  the relative docker path on the right hand side wont work.

`COPY . app/`

should be

`COPY . /app/`

Comment: I have not set `WORKDIR`--if you see my edit, I pasted what Heroku wrote about their WORKDIR. It's the reason why I haven't touched it.   `COPY . /app/` is the second one I tried. I just tried it now, alone, without the other instructions. Still nothing shows when I run `ls` in bash.

Comment: It's quite strange, since after I ran the edit you suggested, I had to change my `RUN` command to `RUN /app/manage.py collectstatic --no-input` in order to find `manage.py`..Which should mean that it exists.

Comment: Can you actually post your full docker file?  Without it, there is no way of helping you.

Comment: Also, when you bash into the directory, you are in the home directory, not where files are copied.  I suspect you are looking in the wrong folder within the container.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of nelsonenzo above is correct. You need WORKDIR statement before the COPY because the WORKDIR command will do both creating the folder and changing into that folder.

WORKDIR /app is equivalent to mkdir /app and CD /app

Try this in your Dockerfile:

```
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app/
```